# Javascript how to calculate values inside array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array :

```
arr = ["003448", "003609", "003729", "003800", "004178", "004362", "004410"];
```

I want to convert it become like this :

```
new_arr =  [161, 120, 71, 378, 184, 48];
```

161 result from 003609 - 003448

120 result from 003729 - 003609

and so on..

The rule is "The next value will be reduced by previous value". I have no clue with this. Anyone please help me.. I will be highly appreciate.

Comment: _"The next value will be [reduced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) by previous value"_

Comment: yes.. if we have array like this [1, 5, 9, 12] then by following the rule it will become 5-1 = 4, 9-5 = 4, 12-9 = 3 then the new array is [4, 4, 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below solution:

```js
var arr = ["003448", "003609", "003729", "003800", "004178", "004362", "004410"];
var new_arr =  [];

for (var i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
  new_arr.push(arr[i]-arr[i-1]);
}

console.log(new_arr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. This is great!

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to scream [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var arr = ["003448", "003609", "003729", "003800", "004178", "004362", "004410"];
var new_array = arr.reduce(function(a, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  var previousValue = array[currentIndex - 1];
  if (previousValue !== undefined)
    a.push(parseInt(currentValue, 10) - parseInt(previousValue, 10));
  return a;
 }, []);

 console.log(new_array);
```

Comment: Note that the `parseInt()` calls are redundant, because the `-` operator coerces its arguments to be numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
   new_arr[] = parseInt(arr[i+1])-parseInt(arr[i])
```